# How to implement my own selectAll: for UITextView without subclass it?

Tags: xcode, uitextview, xib, ibaction

How do I implement my own selectAll: for UITextView without subclassing it? I don't want to subclass UITextView because if I do I need to change every place in my codes (.m/.xib) that need to use this subclass.

I had thought (wrongly!) that maybe I can connect UITextView action like selectAll: to my code (I do declare - (IBAction)select:(id)sender in my h file) ? I drag the action to File's Owner or to .h/.m file, nothing happens.

Now I know they are received action so I can't do that. Then how to ?

[image]

Comment: It is not an action.  It is a received action. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I want to replace the default selectAll: action with my own implementation. But I don't want to subclass UITextView to do it. I really hope it should be a simple action.

Comment: That's silly. Of course you will have to subclass. I told you: it is not an action. It is a received action. It is not emitted by the text view. It is sent _to_ the text view, as a nil targeted action passing up the responder chain.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect it because there is no such action. You are reading the Connections inspector incorrectly. The things in your screen shot are not actions. `selectAll:` is not an action. It is a *received* action. It is not emitted by the text view. It is sent *to* the text view, as a nil targeted action passing up the responder chain. To change or add to the text view behavior when it receives this action, you subclass UITextView. It's easy to do.